# how to parse xml file to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlserializer

I'm trying to parse xml file and xsl files as strings in my code but unable to convert it.
I tried with below code.

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString("xmldata/map_packages.xml");
var str1 = s.serializeToString("packagemappings.xsl");
alert(str)
alert(str1)
```

Getting below error, please check.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: XMLSerializer serializes a DOM node, not a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer Why would you want to serialize an XML file to... XML? It's already serialized.

Comment: The actual requirement is that I want to take this xml files as  a string, so by checking some methods I thought xmlserializetostirng method is good to proceed but I couldn't make it possible.